# Passing image between two VC using Modal Segue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I'm trying to pass data, using delegate between two VC, but I can't get why it's not working.

My first VC

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

    func downloadPhoto() {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhotoFromInternet", sender: nil)

    }

}

extension ViewController: IPresentaionPhotoFormInternetDelegate {

    func setNewImage(imageToShow: UIImage) {
        profileImage.image = imageToShow
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? PresentPhotoFromInternetViewController {
            destination.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

My second VC

```
class PresentPhotoFromInternetViewController: UIViewController { 

 var imageToSend: UIImage?
 var delegate: IPresentaionPhotoFormInternetDelegate?
@IBOutlet weak var photoCollectionView: UICollectionView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        photoCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false

}

    @IBAction func sendPhotoToPreviousController(_ sender: Any) {

        delegate?.setNewImage(imageToShow: iamgeToSend!)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendPhoto", sender: nil)

    }

extension PresentPhotoFromInternetViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! photoCollectionViewCell

        print("Cell is selected")
        iamgeToSend = cell.photoImageView.image
        cell.selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }

protocol IPresentaionPhotoFormInternetDelegate {

    func setNewImage(imageToShow: UIImage)

}
```

I use present modaly segue for from the first VC to the second, and show form the second to the first

When I perform segue from the second VC there is no updates in my first one, although it passes all breakpoints.

Comment: where you assign delegate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is instead of popping controller you are loading completely new controller in your button action

```
@IBAction func sendPhotoToPreviousController(_ sender: Any) {

    delegate?.setNewImage(imageToShow: iamgeToSend!)
    //Comment or remove the performSegue 
    //performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendPhoto", sender: nil)

    //Now simply pop this controller
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    // If you are presenting this controller then you need to dismiss
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

**Note:** If you are segue is kind of `Push` then use `popViewController` or is it kind of `Modal` than you need to use `dismiss`.